# AWS-s3-laravel Graham-Campbell package - Copy all files from one folder to another folder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 image upload in my project. For that i'm using graham-campbell package (https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem/tree/1.0) with Laravel 4.2. In that i can copy single file from one place to another. I can't move all files from one folder to another folder using Flysystem. Anyone have idea, pls shae with me.

Flysystem::copy(string $path, string $newpath);

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not specific to the package however look into how S3 actually works, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/docs/service-s3.rst

Also look in your error logs to see what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. The issue is there is no default method to copy one directory files to another directory. Only copy one file to another directory method available. So i have to loop all files from directory then copy each file to the new path.

Comment: no problem @KalaivananMuthusamy,make this as answered or make your own answer and make that as answered for future people.